# How to retain the position of a scrolled ListView after navigating away to another Activity

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments

I am new to android. I have a Activity where it contains a fragment. In that fragment i have a listview. When I press a listview item it goes to a new activity. But when I press the back button from the tool bar the fragment gets destroyed and created.

So if I scroll to the last item of the listview and goes to a new activity by clicking the last item and when I come back the fragment should appear as I were before clicking the item.

Comment: Questions seeking help must include *the desired behavior*, *a specific problem or error* and *the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1):

When you launch one activity from another activity, there is no connection between them. Killing the new activity should not affect the original activity.

Comment: True, but I believe the Fragment is going to get detached and reattached, therefore resetting the ListView, which is what the question would like not to happen

Comment: This is not true, the fragment would not be detached from its activity unless the activity was destroyed. It would not be detached just because you started a new activity!

Comment: Are fragments not detached when Activitys are paused? I'm not too familiar with the lifecycle events

Comment: No, fragments aren't detached when activites are paused. All that happens is that the onPause() method of the fragment is called. You can see from this graphic that the fragment is not detached until the activity is destroyed: https://developer.android.com/images/activity_fragment_lifecycle.png